Getting Model Properties Immediately After Translation Job is Complete
I am currently creating an upload and translation job from the model derivative API, and I want to to get the properties of the uploaded model immediately after the the translation finishes. However, I tried using model derivative's getAllProperties function after the translation finishes, but I get nothing. What can I do here?
const obj = await uploadObject(file.name, file.path, req.fields.bucketKey);
const modelZipEntrypoint = req.fields['model-zip-entrypoint'] as unknown;
const job = await translateObject(urnify(obj.objectId), modelZipEntrypoint as string);

await modelDerivativeClient.getAllProperties(access_token, urn, modelGuid); // HERE 

export const uploadObject = async (objectName: string, filePath: string, bucket) => {
  await doesBucketExists(bucket);
  const { access_token } = await getInternalToken();
  const obj = await ossClient.upload(bucket, objectName, filePath, access_token);
  return obj;
}

export const translateObject = async (urn: string, rootFileName: string) => {
  const { access_token } = await getInternalToken();
  const job = await modelDerivativeClient.startJob(access_token, {
    input: {
      urn,
      compressedUrn: !!rootFileName,
      rootFileName
    },
    output: {
      formats: [{
        views: [View._2d, View._3d],
        type: Type.Svf
      }],
    }
  });

  return job;
}

Expecting: the data.collections is not empty.

Please note that after triggering the translation, you need to ensure it has finished successfully before querying the design data.
Refer to these steps
To check the translation status, you can use the method below:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autodesk.ModelDerivative;
using Autodesk.ModelDerivative.Model;

public record TranslationStatus(string Status, string Progress, IEnumerable<string>? Messages);

public partial class APS
{
    public async Task<TranslationStatus> GetTranslationStatus(string urn)
    {
        var auth = await GetInternalToken();
        var modelDerivativeClient = new ModelDerivativeClient(_sdkManager);
        try
        {
            var manifest = await modelDerivativeClient.GetManifestAsync(urn, accessToken: auth.AccessToken);
            var messages = new List<string>();
            return new TranslationStatus(manifest.Status, manifest.Progress, messages);
        }
        catch (ModelDerivativeApiException ex)
        {
            if (ex.HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return new TranslationStatus("n/a", "", null);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

This is implemented in details in our Simple Viewer Tutorial
